# Indexing lines in a Python file

Tags: python, file, indexing

I want to open a file, and simply return the contents of said file with each line beginning with the line number.

So hypothetically if the contents of `a` is

```
a

b

c
```

I would like the result to be

```
1: a

2: b

3: c
```

Im kind of stuck, tried enumerating but it doesn't give me the desired format.

Is for Uni, but only a practice test.

A couple bits of trial code to prove I have no idea what I'm doing / where to start

```
def print_numbered_lines(filename):
    """returns the infile data with a line number infront of the contents"""
    in_file = open(filename, 'r').readlines()
    list_1 = []
    for line in in_file:
        for item in line:
            item.index(item)
            list_1.append(item)
    return list_1

def print_numbered_lines(filename):
    """returns the infile data with a line number infront of the contents"""
    in_file = open(filename, 'r').readlines()
    result = []
    for i in in_file:
        result.append(enumerate(i))
    return result
```

Comment: Maintaining an index(initialized to 0) inside the loop by incrementing it by 1 at every iteration will do the job

Comment: @abccd added in a couple of examples, but I wasnt saving any of the things I was trying. Because I wasnt achieving anything, so I dont really have any copies proving I cant do it. But I tried to recreate a couple of them

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A file handle can be treated as an iterable.

```
with open('tree_game2.txt') as f:
   for i, line in enumerate(f):
   print ("{0}: {1}".format(i+1,line))
```

Comment: You can pass enumerate the start value: `enumerate(f, 1)`. No `+1` needed then.

Comment: Mobster kill straight from Sicily ;)

Comment: Delighted to meet a fellow chess player

Comment: this worked perfectly, to be honest we haven't covered 'with' yet. Doing more research now.
Is there a way I can add a ':' after the index number (no whitespaces)? I tried

(i + 1, ':', line) 

which is the closest I've gotten to desired effect, other variations result in errors, mainly incompatible operand types.

Comment: please see the update. Using with here basically saves you from having to close the file at the end.

Answer (score 1):

There seems no need to write a python script, `awk` would solve your problem.

```
 awk '{print NR": "$1}' your_file > new_file
```

Comment: It's for a practice test for uni - chances are that it being in python is mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

What about using an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html)

```
from collections import OrderedDict

c = OrderedDict()
n = 1
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        c.update({n:line})
        #if you just want to print it, skip the dict part and just do:
        print n,line
        n += 1
```

Then you can print it out with:

```
for n,line in c.iteritems(): #.items() if Python3
    print k,line
```

Comment: An ordered dictionary or even a simple dictionary would be an unwanted expense here. Consider if you had a 10MB file. How much extra time and memory will it take?

Comment: 10MB is nothing.

Comment: It really depends on what you want to do with the data, if you just want to print it then I agree with you. If you need to use it in your program later, a dict is the best choice.

Comment: on the contrary, a list would be the better choice in that case.

Comment: Again, it depends on what you want to do. Also, considering that he wants the index starting at 1, a dict looks a cleaner option to me.

Answer (score 0):

the simple way to do it:
1st:with open the file -----2ed:using count mechanism: 
for example:

```
data = object of file.read()
lines = data.split("\n")

count =0
for line in lines:
    print("line "+str(count)+">"+str()+line)
    count+=1
```