# how to auto increment numbers in a text file?

Tags: python

I don't know if my title is the correct wording for what I want to do so I will explain.

My code :

```
def add_new_employee():  # Creates a function named 'add_new_employee'
    with open("records.txt", "a+") as storing_records:  # Opens the record text file for append+ so that anything written to the text file will be written to the end and also so I can read the file
        last_record = records[-1]  # Creates a variable called last_record and stores the values of the records variable inside, then it gets the last value in the list.
        print("\nThe last record in the file is:\n" + last_record, "\n" + "\nPlease enter the number that comes after the previous user ID")  # Prints the last_record variable
        another_record = "y"  # Creates a variable called another_Record and sets it to 'y'
        while another_record == "y" or another_record == "Y":  # Creates a while loop that will keep running as long as the another_Record variable is set to 'y' or 'Y'
            employee_number = input("\nEnter your employee number:")  # Stores the users input in the employee_number variable
            employee_name = input("\nEnter your name:")  # Stores the users input in the employee_name variable
            employee_age = input("\nEnter your age:")  # Stores the users input in the employee_age variable
            employee_position = input("\nEnter your position:")  # Stores the users input in the employee_position variable
            employee_salary = input("\nEnter your salary:")  # Stores the users input in the employee_salary variable
            employee_years = input("\nEnter the amount of years you have been employed:")  # Stores the users input in the employee_years variable
            user_input_record = employee_number + ', ' + employee_name + ', ' + employee_age + ', ' + employee_position + ', ' + employee_salary + ', ' + employee_years  # Adds all the user inputs together and separates them with comas
            storing_records.write(user_input_record + "\n")  # Stores the user input in the records text file
            another_record = input("\n\033[33m" + "Do you want to input another record? (yes/no): " + "\033[39m").lower()  # Asks the user if they want to add another record, if the user types 'y' or 'Y' then the while loops will run again
    if another_record == 'yes':
        add_new_employee()  # If the user types anything but yes then the add_new_employee function will run
    else:
        main()  # Returns the user to the main function
```

I ask the user to enter in a userID but instead of asking I want it to be automatically created based on the previous userID in the file. So if the last userID was 023 I want the program to automatically make the next userID 024 so that there is no chance of the user messing up the order of the userID numbers

My textFile format:

```
#EMP_NO, EMP_NAME, AGE, POSITION, SALARY, YRS_EMP   
001, Peter Smyth, 26, Developer, 29000, 4
002, Samuel Jones, 23, Developer, 24000, 1
003, Laura Stewart, 41, DevOps, 42000, 15
004, Paul Jones, 24, Analyst, 21000, 2
005, Simon Brown, 52, Developer, 53000, 18
006, George Staples, 42, Tester, 42000, 12
007, Greg Throne, 57, DevOps, 50000, 23
008, Aston Bently, 27, Tester, 33000, 5
009, Ben Evans, 32, DevOps, 38000, 2
010, Emma Samson, 23, DevOps, 22000, 1
011, Stephanie Beggs, 43, Tester, 19000, 9
012, Sarah McQuillin, 47, DevOps, 23000, 5
013, Grace Corrigan, 48, Analyst, 44000, 16
014, Simone Mills, 32, DevOps, 32000, 11
015, Martin Montgomery, 28, Analyst, 28000, 3
016, Darren Downing, 19, Developer, 24000, 5
017, Jack Campbell, 22, Designer, 20000, 2
018, Jake Peachey, 19, Designer, 20000, 4
019, Darren Downing, 19, Developer, 30000, 4
020, Jack Campbell, 21, Designer, 20090, 3
021, Darren Downing, 29, DevOps, 20000, 4
022, Megan Mckinstry, 20, Designer, 39000, 5
```

Comment: I don't think there's a way to "auto increment", but since the file handle is an iterable, you can point it to the EOF and backtrack to the last newline character. Then, using find the substring between the last newline character and the next comma, which should contain your written indices. Also check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43993429/indexing-lines-in-a-python-file) for more info, and [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_methods.htm) for methods you can use on the file object.

Comment: I'm pretty new to python so I don't completely understand what you are saying to do but thank you for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a comment, but I'll provide an example that you should be able to integrate into your solution to find the employee number.

```
with open('example.txt', 'a+') as f:
    # Gives us the cursor position, which is currently at the end of the file, 
    # since we're using 'a+' mode
    endOfFile = f.tell()

    num_characters_to_read = 1
    num_newlines_to_ignore = 2
    initial_backward_buffer = num_characters_to_read + num_newlines_to_ignore

    # While we haven't hit the beginning of the file
    while f.tell() != 0: 
        # We traverse the file backwards and read the character at the cursor position
        f.seek(f.tell()-initial_backward_buffer)
        value = f.read(1)               

        # We know that the employee number will be at the start of the line,
        # and immediately before the previous line's newline (\n) character
        if value == '\n':
            # Get the position of the start of the line
            line_start = f.tell()
            emp_num = ""

            # And begin reading the numbers of the employee ID...
            while True:
                value = f.read(1)

                # ...and append them to our string
                if value != ',':
                    emp_num = emp_num + value
                else: # When we hit a comma, we know our "emp_num" string will contain the ID
                    break
            break # Break from the outer while loop

    # Return to the end of file, and continue from there
    f.seek(endOfFile)

    # At this point, the variable "emp_num" holds the employee ID as a string and you'll have to
    # manipulate it accordingly.
```

To give a brief explanation, when we open the file, our `f` is a Python file object. This object has [some methods and functions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_methods.htm) that it can use (e.g. `read()`, `seek()`, etc.). Essentially, some of the methods allow us to use the file object like a "cursor" when we're typing.

When we open the file with the `a+` flag, the cursor is at the end of the file. (*This makes sense, since if we wanted to append to the file, the cursor would have to be at the end.*) In my example, I use functions like `tell()` and `seek()` to "tell" me where the cursor is and to "seek", or move it, backwards until I find the employee number. I then use the `read()` function to read in every individual character and append it to my employee ID string variable, where you can use it accordingly for the rest of your program.

Comment: Thank you for the example, it makes a lot of sense now

Comment: @Darren_D19 If this answer helps or does solve your problem, please select it as the Accepted Answer!